# How to run external sql script file from an asp.net application. to create a duplicate database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-schema, database-migration

I want to create a copy of existing db with a new name from an asp.net application.
How can i do this?

I think i can take the script of existing db and run it to create a new db.
Pls provide me a good solution.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE" + " " + dbname;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("D:\\DBWithOUTData.sql");
            string myTestSql = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            string script = myTestSql.Replace("GO", "");
            script = script.Replace("go", "");
            script = "use " + dbname + ";" + script;

            using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(script, con);

            } retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();`
```

While running the script, it results timeout exception, even when the connection is set without timeout.
Is this a good way of doing this.?

Comment: You could create a single SQL script that creates a new database and all the tables,views,etc within it; you can generate these easily enough from SQL Enterprise Manager or (with a lot more effort) by code. Why do you want to do this though ?

Comment: Hi . Thanks  for reply. I have the script file of dB. (or notepad file). I want to read that file from ASP.NET application to create the duplicate of database with a given name.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the new database name, validate it and execute your script just as well from a webform or MVC app as you can from a WinForms app.

I wouldn't do what you're wanting to do, but hey it's your scenario and who am I to argue :)

You should simply be able to replace a database name token i.e. ***DBNAMEGOESHERE*** in your SQL script with (whatever the user entered into the textbox), and use a SqlCommand to execute your script.

Let me know if you need any more than that..

Comment: Hi Sh1rts. I've created db. But geting TimeOut error while running the script, if db is big. Pls note the edited question.

Comment: Increase the timeout in your connection string - http://forums.asp.net/t/1389167.aspx

Comment: I've set no time out. Maybe its because of errors in query,deadlocks etc? if so how can i solve this? –  Instead of running script,can i attach .mdf/.ldf file of Db to create new one. Pls give me some links.

Comment: What do you mean "no timeout" ? If there are errors in your query, SQL Profiler is your friend.

Comment: I.ve not given " time out"  in connection string.can i attach .mdf/.ldf file of existing  Db to create new one?

Comment: I've never tried to do that programmatically, I guess it must be possible. You need to break up your Create Database script and debug it, find out what is taking so long; that would be the safer approach I think.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is it mandatory to write an asp.net code for this?
Else it would have been better to create a batch file for this which can make the work more easy.

But if, to write a .net code, its better to make a windows form application, where you capture some information like the new database name and then on a button click on that windows form, execute the commands or execute a batch file to create a new db with a new name.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have .sql file of the dB. and am using asp.net. I need the code to read that sql file and create  a duplicate of the db with a given name